# How to convert images like JPEG, PNG, etc. to WebP with ColdFusion while maintaining the metadata?

Tags: coldfusion, webp

I'm looking for an effective method for automating the conversion of a number of images to the WebP image format. I'm particularly interested in a method that will keep the metadata or allow me to add or edit the metadata.

Comment: Good news: http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57575523-93/google-to-fix-some-webp-image-format-shortcomings/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be `<cfexecute>` with `cwebp` https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/precompiled

As for metadata...

> WebP format do support EXIF/XMP metadata. The next version of WebP library (libwebp) will have appropriate APIs supporting handling of
>   EXIF/XMP metadata, along with supporting utility binaries to convert
>   JPEG/PNG to WebP format retaining the metadata from original files.

Quoted from WebP Google Group.  Meanwhile, follow issue 52 for latest updates? https://code.google.com/p/webp/issues/detail?id=52